# Sobel filter wrong result

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, convolution, sobel

I'm writing an Sobel filter with python,
but result seem differntce from other one ,
Is there any mistake from my code?
Or am  I misunderstand the sobol filter

and there is my result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('Lenna.png',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)


def convolution(img,rowMask,columnsMask,maskSize,r):


    outPut = np.zeros((len(img),len(img[0])))
    img = np.pad(img,r,"constant")

    for y in range(0,len(outPut)):
        for x in range(0,len(outPut[0])):
            outPut[y][x] = convolutionRow(img,y+r, x+r, maskSize,rowMask,r)

    for y in range(0,len(outPut)):
        for x in range(0,len(outPut[0])):
            outPut[y][x] = convolutionColumns(img,y+r, x+r, maskSize,columnsMask,r)

    return outPut


def convolutionRow(img,y,x,maskSize,rowMask,r):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,maskSize):
        sum += img[y][x-r+i]*rowMask[i]
    return sum

def convolutionColumns(img,y,x,maskSize,columnsMask,r):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0,maskSize):
        sum += img[y-r+i][x]*columnsMask[i]
    return sum

SobelXRowMask=np.array([0.125,0.25,0.125])
SobelXColumnsMask=np.array([-0.125,0,0.125])

SobelX = convolution(img, SobelXRowMask, SobelXColumnsMask,3,1)
cv2.imshow('SobelXOutPut',SobelX)


SobelYRowMask=np.array([-0.125,0,0.125])
SobelYColumnsMask=np.array([0.125,0.25,0.125])

SobelY = convolution(img, SobelYRowMask, SobelYColumnsMask,3,1)
cv2.imshow('SobelYOutPut',SobelY)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please edit to fix your typos.

Comment: I don't have time to fully check your code but what I saw within a second is that you convolve your `rowMask` with `img` and your `colMask` with `img`. What you actually want to do is to convolve the result of `img` and one mask, with the second mask. Otherwise you just overwrite the result of the first convolution with the second. So you're actually not calculating a separated Sobel filter atm. and for some reason your code takes like 20 seconds on my computer. I would assume a few milliseconds. but maybe someting is wrong with my computer.